# Java Timer only fire once (server only issue)

Tags: java, windows, server, hardware

Ok this is a weird one and it does not appear to be a coding issue. I have Intellij installed on both my home computer and my server computer (Both running windows pro). I remote in and have it side by side. Both with Intellij open and both with the same copy and pasted code. On my home computer this code works perfectly, it will fire once every 60 seconds. But on the server computer it fires once and it will not fire again. I have packaged it into a jar and ran the jars and same thing, it runs once and never runs again. Here is the code.

```
public class BackupTask extends TimerTask {
    private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> df = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>(){
        @Override
        protected DateFormat initialValue() {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH_mm_ss");
        }
    };

    public void run() {
        try {
            File src = new File("C:\\Users\\justi\\Desktop\\Server\\Saved");
            File dest = new File("\\\\READYSHARE\\USB_Storage\\Backups\\" + df.get().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

            if(!dest.exists()){
                dest.mkdir();
            }

            copyFolder(src, dest);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest)
            throws IOException{

        if(src.isDirectory()){

            //if directory not exists, create it
            if(!dest.exists()){
                dest.mkdir();
            }

            //list all the directory contents
            String files[] = src.list();

            for (String file : files) {
                //construct the src and dest file structure
                File srcFile = new File(src, file);
                File destFile = new File(dest, file);
                //recursive copy
                copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            }

        }else{
            //if file, then copy it
            //Use bytes stream to support all file types
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

AutoBackup.java

```
public class AutoBackup {
//    Timer timer;

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private final int TIME_BETWEEN_SAVES = 60;

    public AutoBackup(){
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new BackupTask(), 10, TIME_BETWEEN_SAVES, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoBackup();
//        Timer timer = new Timer();
//        timer.schedule(new BackupTask(), 1000, 60 * 1000);
    }
}
```

This program is just a very simply copy and paste from one location to another on a scheduled interval. I have also tried running Intellij as admin and I am just out of ideas on why this would be happening. Server computer has a core i5-4690k, Micro ITX Gigabyte Ultra Durable GA-H97N-WIFI H97 motherboard with 16 gigs of ram. Let me know if there is any other information that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you described is very strange, but I came out with one case when your code may fail. Let me describe it in details. You first create new scheduled executor with a thread pool size = 1:

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

This single thread will be used to execute your runnables. Then you schedule runnable with fixed rate, to be run first after 10 seconds, and then every 60 seconds:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new BackupTask(), 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Now, because you have only one thread in executor that can run your runnables, when your BackupTask hang for any reason, or maybe execute much much longer, the next execution will be delayed as long as the first one completes. You are doing network backup, so the issue may be network related. Just for example - doing close() may result in code waiting for network timeout (depending how long timeout value is), or doing write(..) in the same scenario.

What I would suggest is to put some debug statements in your code (please see code below). I know this may generate some rubbish in the application console, but if you do not want to debug remotely, this may be the only way to find out what is wrong in your code.

```
public static void copyFolder(File src, File dest) throws IOException{
    if (src.isDirectory()) {

        //if directory not exists, create it
        if(!dest.exists()){
            System.out.println("Creating directory " + dest);
            dest.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Created directory ");
        }

        for (String file : src.list()) {

            File srcFile = new File(src, file);
            File destFile = new File(dest, file);

            System.out.println("Copying " + srcFile + " to " + destFile);
            copyFolder(srcFile,destFile);
            System.out.println("Copied " + srcFile + " to " + destFile);
        }

    }else{

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        System.out.println("Writing file " + src + " to " + dest);

        int length;
        //copy the file content in bytes
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        System.out.println("Closing file " + src);
        in.close();

        System.out.println("Closing file " + dest);
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Writing file " + src + " to " + dest + " is done");
    }
}
```

Also, my few comments in regards to your code:

Your BackupTask extends TimerTask. This is unnecessary. It's enough for it to implement Runnable.

When you write/read from streams you should always make sure to close your resources in finally section, or use try with resources (from Java 7 upward). Otherwise you may be left with files open forever.

```
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;

try {
  in = new FileInputStream(src);
  out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
  while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
  }
} finally {
  if (in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  if (out != null) {
    try {
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion/ code review! I love when people explain some things I have done wrong. Ill try to implement this when I get home and I will make sure to change the stream closing in a finally catch and I will update with what I find. Thanks a lot for the help! I was not sure where to even start looking :), at least this gives me some ideas to try and see what happens. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok now i am going to feel stupid admitting this but.... I was not using the same data sets when testing on both the server and on my machine. I then realized after getting back home that the files I was trying to back up are really big... It was taking around 10 - 15 minutes to back up to the network drive. I am not even sure how I did not notice/ think of such a simple thing. Thank you for the help and advice on the finally.